# Programmatically change ClickOnce update URL within the installed app

Tags: clickonce

There are many questions and potential solutions for moving ClickOnce apps to other servers, but I was not able to find a solution that addresses my particular issue, as follows:

We have a ClickOnce app that is used in a number of plants throughout the world.  A user in China, for example, would install the app from a server located in China to minimize the startup delay when new versions are deployed (a frequent occurrence).  When that same user comes to the US with his laptop and runs the app here, ClickOnce will, of course, continually update from China URL, which causes a significant startup delay.

What I would like to do is to create a function that will change the ClickOnce update URL on the user's machine to another URL that will provide a faster load, for the next and subsequent times that the app is run.

All installation servers are updated when a new version is published and all therefore have exactly the same stuff, so the user could, of course, uninstall the app and then reinstall it from a local server.  But that is a pain that I would like to avoid.

I understand that this will require identifying the correct manifest file, modifying the URL, re-signing the file, and possibly other steps.  Can this be done?

We are using framework 4.5, and C# in VS 2015.

Comment: Look at this link if it's of any help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5309f67e-efe4-40b4-b937-aed18cf87155/clickonce-change-deployment-url-after-publish?forum=winformssetup

Answer (score 0):

you can use mage to change lot many properties of `ClickOnce` manifest after publishing

`mage.exe -Update my2.application -ProviderUrl myproviderURL`

But you might have to sign the package again.